# Why does await not ensure order of execution in a method?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, post, promise, xmlhttprequest

Hello i have the following problem:

I am performing two `async` requests to a server on a button press.
The first `async` call is actually a call to a javascript native method which submits a form.
The second `async` call is a `post` using a service.
I do not understand why the second request sometimes happens before the first:

```
declare function submit(id: string): any;

 @Component({
  selector: 'index',
  templateUrl: './index.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./index.component.css']
  })
 export class IndexComponent implements OnInit {

 public viewComputers: Computer[] = null;
 public catalog: Catalog = null;

 constructor(private service: AnubisService) { }

 async refreshListAsync() {
     this.catalog = await this.service.getCatalogAsync(); //post call to a server
     this.viewComputers = this.catalog.computers.items;
  }

 async cbSubmitAsync() {
     var result = this.submit("clientForm");  --call to js submit form method
     await this.refreshListAsync();  //how can this happen before the first call 
 }
}
```

**Javascript call**

```
 function submit(id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var form = document.getElementById(id);
            form.onerror = () => {
                reject("could not post");
            }
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var action = form.getAttribute('action');
            var method = form.getAttribute('method');
            xhr.open(method, action);

            xhr.onload = function () {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    resolve(xhr.response);
                }
                else if (xhr.status != 200) {
                    reject("Failed to submit form with status" + xhr.status);
                }
            }
            var data = new FormData(form);
            xhr.send(data);
        });
    }
```

**Service Post call**

```
public async getCatalogAsync():Promise<Catalog>{
    let route=this.BaseUrl+"/api/admin/get-catalog";

    try  {
      var data=await this.http.get<Catalog>(route).toPromise<Catalog>();

      return data;
    }catch(ex){
      return null;
    }
  }
```

My questions is: inside `cbSubmitAsync` method , how can the second call happen before the first and if so , how can i wrap it in a promise (i have also tried await-ing the `submit` and to no avail)

Comment: you told (I have also tried await-ing the submit and to no avail) what this mean?
do you mean 
`var result = await this.submit("clientForm");` in `cbSubmitAsync` method. 
if so it should work I believe

Comment: I have tried `submit` and `await submit`

Comment: it should work with just adding await.I tried this scenario it worked perfectly fine with me so can you please create JSFiddle with your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `await`on the first line of your `cbSubmitAsync()` method, since `this.submit(..)` already returns a `Promise`:

```js
var result = await this.submit("clientForm");
```

```js
function submit() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Waited 500ms.");
      resolve();
    }, 500);
  });
}

async function cbSubmitAsync() {
  console.log("start");
  await submit();
  console.log("finished.");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="cbSubmitAsync()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: I have also used `await` to no avail.

Comment: `await` on that line is prerequisite for "waiting" to happen. Perhaps you have another bug inside of your `submit` method. Try with `await` and debug the code.

Comment: @Nenad by default async flag will be true no need to pass. see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/open#Parameters

Comment: @AminKodaganur right, I was searching for some problem in the code too hard.

Comment: I believe it should work by just adding await while submit calling

Comment: I did try with `await` too and it does not.The second call gets executed before.Can i somehow make the declaration of the `js` method `async` ? Something like `declare async submit(data:string)` .

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian you are doing something else wrong here. I added simplified example. Everything works fine.